# Easy to reach day-hikes in the Italian Appennini and Alpi with public transport?

Tags: italy, hiking

I live in Bologna, and I want to go for a day hike or something in the next week or so, however, I don't have a car, and since it is august, most accommodation is booked in the areas of high tourism (Gran Paradiso, i Dolomiti etc). I was wondering if there are any easy to access hikes with just buses and trains etc. 
Thanks!

Comment: Related (no answers there, though):  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/140297/dolomites-in-september-end-using-public-transport